# Docker: "wait-for-it" script does not start the application when MySQL is ready

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I am using Docker-Compose and [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) to start my backend with Node.js once the MySQL service is ready to receive connections. My problem is that the script does not realize the connection is ready by itself. I can make it work if I set the timeout to 20s since MySQL would be running by then, but that could change in different environments and the app would crash if it took more time for a specific environment. I want it to check it periodically since I think it is the right thing to do.

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:

  app:
    image: pfmc
    ports:
      - 4005:4005
    working_dir: /usr/src/app
    command: sh -c './wait-for-it.sh -t 0 db:3306 -- npm start'
    environment: 
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pfmc123
      MYSQL_HOST: mysql
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pfmc123
      MYSQL_DATABASE: pfmc

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./db-startup:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pfmc123
      MYSQL_DATABASE: pfmc
```

The logs:

```
app_1    | wait-for-it.sh: waiting for db:3306 without a timeout
mysql_1  | 2020-05-25 19:59:58+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.30-1debian10 started.
mysql_1  | 2020-05-25 19:59:58+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
mysql_1  | 2020-05-25 19:59:58+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.30-1debian10 started.
mysql_1  | 2020-05-25 19:59:58+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
```

and it stays at this point:

```
mysql_1  | 2020-05-25T20:00:08.243448Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
mysql_1  | Version: '5.7.30'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: can you please also post you /wait-for-it.sh file ?

Comment: @NiteshSharma the file is the one included in the repo link I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have one issues in here: your MySQL container is a service named `mysql` not `db` you should either adapt the service to be named `db` or the `wait-for-it` invocation to poll on a connection to `mysql:3306`

All together, your *docker-compose.yml* should look like this – I added the fix with comment stating `@fixme`:

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:

  app:
    image: pfmc
    ports:
      - 4005:4005
    working_dir: /usr/src/app
    command: sh -c './wait-for-it.sh -t 0 db:3306 -- npm start'
    environment: 
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pfmc123
      # A first @fixme is here 
      MYSQL_HOST: db
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pfmc123
      MYSQL_DATABASE: pfmc

  # And a second @fixme is here
  db: 
    image: mysql:5
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./db-startup:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pfmc123
      MYSQL_DATABASE: pfmc
```

Comment: Fantastic! One thing though before accepting this answer. I had to change the value of `MYSQL_HOST:` from `mysql` to `db` to match the new container name. Now it works like a charm, thank you very much!